# When pressing enter in textbox, how do I focus on submit button using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a page with multiple textboxes and each has a button associated with it. This works as a search 'hub', I suppose, where the user can search by ID, name etc.

When entering a search term for e.g. name however, pressing enter 'clicks' the very first button on the page (ID search), causing an error if the associated textbox is empty (which it would be if someone meant to search by name).

I have attempted to rectify this using JQuery, and have written the following:

```
$('input:text').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next('input:button').focus();
    });
```

I'm simply using the click event so that I can monitor where focus is redirected, but eventually I would use .keypress. However, nothing happens upon clicking a textbox and I can't see for the life of me what is wrong with the JQuery.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

To elaborate on the problem, the .NET code used looks similar to the following throughout the page.

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:100">Company ID</td>
    <td style="margin-left:3px;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="...TextBox" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="...NameSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" /></td></tr>
```

This is generating this (view source):

```
<td><input name="...TextBox" id="...TextBox" style="width: 230px;" type="text"/></td>
<td><input name="...NameSearch" class="Button" id="...NameSearch" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('...NameSearch','')" type="button" value="Search"/></td>
```

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: I see you mentioned you can't link the site, but it would still be very helpful if you could post some HTML with your question - even dummy html that has the correct structure - which would reveal nothing about your site.

Comment: I appreciate that, I've now added some markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input:text')keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $("input:submit", $(this).closest('tr')).eq(0).focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the keypress, I've got something similar to work in another scenario, it seems to be specifically locating the next button that's the problem.

Comment: That did indeed work, thank you. Well, with a . before keydown and with "input:button" =P. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Are these submit buttons?  If so clicking on one will submit the data for all of them.  It sounds more like an HTML problem than jQuery.  Could you link the site?

Comment: If you have multiple submit buttons I'd recommend breaking the fields into multiple forms.  But I don't know the specifications of your project so...

Comment: No, they're just buttons. I can't really change the page too much, as I'm working with someone else's markup. And unfortunately I can't really link the site, sorry. I know that's not overly helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to focus the button you want to click, cancel the submit request by the textfield, and instead trigger a click on whatever button you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is your submit button the exact next sibling of the textbox? If not, then the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function is not what you want. If there is anything else in the dom between the two, you can use [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to find it instead.

**Update**

Now that you have added your markup to the question, I can see why neither of these next() functions work -- your button is not a sibling of the textbox (because they are wrapped in separate table cells).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to automatically click the button when you press enter in the text box, you don't need jquery to do this. Look into the `DefaultButton` property of the asp Panel control

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="myButton">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I don't want a default button, as each of the buttons may be clicked. Admittedly I could move button/textbox pairs into panels to facilitate this, but jquery seems quicker...

Comment: right, each button/textbox pair would be in it's own panel. Are you looking for 'quicker' in performance, or to implement? I'm curious on what the performance differences would be. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean quicker in a performance sense, simply to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use next() because the textbox and the button are not on the same level of the DOM. Your button has an ID, you could use $('#...NameSearch').focus();

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the ID, since the markup I provided is just a snapshot, there are many different pairs of textboxes and buttons and I need each textbox to trigger the nearest button.